# How can I find the License Key for a stream?

Tags: video, video-streaming, drm, m3u, mpd

I have a livestream that is in mpd format, but it is encrypted with DRM, how do I get the key to stream it to Chromecast?

the link mentioned is: https://0058-jbc.dtvott.com/dash_live_0038/manifest.mpd?da=1&country=BR&accountType=DTH&deviceType=web

I've already tried looking for a way to get the key, but to no avail. How can I do that?